# is loading all background images different from <img> preloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

i have image slider . it takes time to load images and doesn't look good . is preloading  will work for div background  images.

or are there any way to load all div's background images on load . which i may require later .

```
$.get('photos.xml', function (xml)
{
       $('item', xml).each(function (k)
       {
           frontimg.push($(this).find('frontImg').text());
           stripimg.push($(this).find('stripImg').text());

           arrBackImg.push($(this).find('backImg').text());
           backText.push($(this).find('backTxt').text());

           //frontDiv.push("<h2>"+fTitle[k]+"</h2>"+ "<h3>"+fCity[k]+"</h3><hr><h4>YEAR OF COMPLETION</h4>"+fYear[k]+"<hr><h4>LOCATION</h4>"+fLoc[k]+"<hr><h4>PROPERTY TYPE</h4>"+fType[k]+"<hr><h4>MAPLETREE'S TYPE</h4>"+fRole[k]);

           frontDiv.push("");
           $('#myImageFlow').append('<div id="id' + k + '" alt="div' + k + '" class="sliderImage" width="280" height="310" style="visibility:hidden"> <div class="ffrontText" id="ff' + k + '">' + frontDiv[k] + '</div><div class="borderdiv" id="b' + k + '"></div><div class="borderdiv1" id="bd' + k + '"></div><div class="reflection" id="ref' + k + '"></div>  <div class="overlay" id="o' + k + '"></div></div>');
       });
});
```

Comment: Can u simulate the same on a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Yes, preloading will work with any image that gets put onto the page. All it does it load the image to the user's computer, then that image stays there and doesn't need to be downloaded when it's used on the page.